# Turn on/off low current device (LED) with Arduino

Tags: arduino-nano, electronics, voltage

I am just starting with Arduino and my first project consists in switching a LED light with Arduino.

I know a relay must be use to control AC high voltage device (i.e. 240V), however, as my LED seems to be powered by DC 7V voltage (7V - 0.43A written on the power supply which is integrated within the outlet, so I can only access the low voltage wire), I am wondering how to control such a device.

Do I still need a relay or the Arduino can handle this on its own?

Comment: Do you have the LED datasheet?

Comment: It's the Jansjo lamp from Ikea. I copy below what's written on the outlet: MODEL: KMV-070-030-GS-3, PRI: 220-240V~50/60Hz 0.05A, SEC: 7V_-- 0.43A 3W    SELV

Comment: Look into MOSFET as a switch

Comment: You could probably run the Arduino from that same 7V supply. Negating the need for a separate adapter.

Comment: @chrisl: would you have a mosfet reference in mind which could do the job?

Comment: I have just found a relay (SRD-05VDC-SL-C) which can handle 10A/30V DC devices so I will start with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use a power MOSFET transistor. This one from Sparkfun is an example: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10213

If you use a relay you will probably need transistor and a separate power supply to drive the relay coils anyway, and will also need a [**flyback diode**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode) to protect the control circuit of the relay from the "back EMF" of the relay coils.

**DO NOT** try to drive relay coils directly from an Arduino digital pin. It will almost certainly fry the Arduino pin, and might destroy the entire Arduino.

A MOSFET transistor like the one I linked can be controlled directly from an Arduino GPIO line, and can switch DC loads of up to 60V and 30A.

Comment: Why would I need an extra power supply while the SRD-05VDC-SL-C relay can be driven with 5V, as output by the Arduino?

Comment: You can drive the control line of a relay like that with 5V, but it needs a 5V supply to drive the relay coils. It **may** be within the current limits of the Arudino's 5V line, but it might also cause the 5V line to bounce around as the relay energizes and de-energizes.

Answer (score -1):

No You can easily achieve this by using a NPN Transistor....

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiMHlR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can use BC548 NPN transistor for this is..

But make sure that ground of both emitter and arduino should be same....

Comment: This transistor is a poor recommendation because the `Collector Current — Continuous` for the BC548 is only 100mA, yet the LED load could be up to 430mA.